# How do I do a GET for Firebase.functions().httpsCallable?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

How do I do a GET for Firebase.functions().httpsCallable?
I keep receiving a POST error 404 but this is a GET request to my server. Should I pass in nothing or there is something to change this httpsCallable to get function?

Client

```
let updateWorkshop = Firebase.functions().httpsCallable('api/update/workshop');

    updateWorkshop({/* nothing */})
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);

      }, err => {
        console.log(err);

      })
```

Server

```
app.get('/v3/update/workshop', asyncMiddleware( async (req, res, next) => {
    let results = await UPDATE_WORKSHOP_DATE.Run()
    res.status(200).json({results: results})
}))

exports.api = FUNCTIONS.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: What exactly are you expecting this to invoke on the backend?  This will only work with a named callbable function on the backend, not some arbitrary HTTP endpoint.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable

Comment: i am trying to do a get request from my server. I testing just using the link on google it works

Answer (score 5):

If you are just trying to ping your callable function endpoint, a GET won't work.  As you can see from the [protocol specification for callable functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference), it uses a POST.  If you use a GET, it's an error because you're not following the protocol.